# How to pass a ListView SubItem text to a label in Windows form application?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, label

I'm trying to create a windows form application to keep track of a bunch of 'things' (it doesn't really matter what).

These things are represented as items in a ListView, with their properties (real-world properties) being sub-items. I also have a few labels.

I need a way to get these labels to change to the text of the SubItems so that when an item in the ListView is selected, the labels all update to their respective SubItem text.

How do I tell the labels where to find the SubItem text? And how can I get them to change to the SubItems of a different ListView item when it is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `SelectedIndexChanged` event to know when the selection has changed, then just map subitem text to the labels:

```
private void lv_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = lv.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text;
    label2.Text = lv.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;
    label3.Text = lv.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text;
}
```

Note that `Item[n]`, `SelectedItems[0]` and `SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0]` all refer to the same thing.

Comment: Thank you very much! Once I realised the index for SubItems starts at 1 and not 0, this solved my problem.

Comment: Thats what that final note is telling you = SubItem[0] is the Item Text.  It os worth knowing that because in other cases you can copy text in a loop.

Comment: New problem! Clicking elsewhere in the ListView or slecting another item causes an outOfRange Exception. How do I handle that error?

Comment: You will have to check that there are some selected items.  `if (lv.SelectedItems.Count > 0) ...`